# Can't change Tree icon in Vaadin

Tags: java, tree, vaadin

I use Vaadin 7. I tried to change the component's icon with the following code :

```
Tree tree = new Tree("The Planets and Major Moons");
tree.setIcon(new ThemeResource("img/inode-directory.png"));
.... //here I fill the tree
```

When I run the application I still get the same icon (default icon) of Vaadin Tree. Is there something that I forgot to add?

Comment: Which icon do you wish to set? The items in the tree or...? Probably you need to specify the icon on item level

Comment: I want to set an icon for all the Tree components. In `tree.setIcon()` description they say that it set all component's icon.

Answer (score 1):

I figured how to change to tree icon in Vaadin. It's simple :

- You have to create you own custom Theme that inherit from the default theme [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html)
- Override the following CSS in your style.css : `.v-tree-node` and `.v-tree-node-expanded`

You can set any img you want from an url like this :

```
.v-tree-node-expanded {
background: transparent url(img/Documenta.png) no-repeat 0px 4px;
}
.v-tree-node {
background: transparent url(img/Documenta.png) no-repeat 0px 4px;
padding: 1px 0;
padding-left: 2px;
}
```